# MSP432 Lauchpad return error 614 while debug

Tags: debugging, embedded, texas-instruments, msp432

Yesterday it is very normal when I run debug in MSP432 Lauchpad. But today, I don't know why and how when I run debug, the Code Composer Studio (CCS) return an error code -614 like this following image:

> CS_DAP_0: Error connecting to the target: (Error -614 @ 0x0) The target indicates there is an error condition from a previous SWD  request. Clear the error the condition, and try the SWD request again. (Emulation package 9.2.1.00046)

[image]

Comment: Did you google the issue first?  Seems a common enough problem discussed at length on the TI support forum.  Try the existing solutions first. e.g: https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/474628?CS-DAP-0-Error-connecting-to-the-target-Error-615-0x0-

Comment: Thank you, man. I reset CCS and the error is gone